# Fill an array with spmd in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, distributed

I have a 1-by-p array R in Matlab (with p large). I initialize this array with all its entries equal to 0 and the i-th element of the array R shall receive the output from `myfunction`, applied to `parameters(i)`. In other words :

```
R=zeros(p,1);
for i=1:p
R(i)=myfunction(parameters(i));
end
```

The same function `myfunction` is applied multiple times with different input. And because p might become large, I recognized a `spmd` problem (single program, multiple data) and thought that using the `spmd` construct would help the previous code run faster.

If I run `matlabpool`, I obtain n_workers different labs. My idea is to break the array R into n_workers different parts and ask each available worker to fill a part of the array. I would like to do something like this :

```
q=((p-1)-mod(p-1,n_workers-1))/(n_workers-1);

lab 1:
for j=1:q
R(j) = myfunction(parameters(j));
end

lab 2:
for j=(q+1):(2*q+1)
R(j) = myfunction(parameters(j));
end

...

lab n_workers:
for j=( q*(n_workers-1)+1 ):p
R(j) = myfunction(parameters(j));
end
```

However, since I'm new to the parallel programming, I don't know how to write this properly in Matlab. Instead of subdividing myself the array R, could I use a `coditributed` array instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if your function evaluations are independent, you might well be better off using `parfor`, like so:

```
R=zeros(p,1);
parfor i=1:p
    R(i)=myfunction(parameters(i));
end
```

`spmd` is generally only useful when you need communication between iterations. In any case, you *can* run this sort of thing inside `spmd` using the [`for-drange` construct](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/using-a-for-loop-over-a-distributed-range-for-drange.html) like so:

```
spmd
    R = codistributed.zeros(p, 1)
    for i = drange(1:p)
        R(i) = myfunction(parameters(i));
    end
end
```

In that case, you'd probably also want to make `parameters` be a distributed array too to avoid having multiple copies in memory. (`parfor` automatically avoids that problem by "slicing" both `R` and `parameters`)